# Prove that $\frac1{1+a}+\frac1{1+b}+\frac1{1+c}\leq\frac14(a+b+c+3)$ if $abc=1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

I found the following exercise in a problem book (with no solutions):

> Given $a,b,c>0$ such that $abc=1$ prove that
> $$\frac{1}{1+a}+\frac{1}{1+b}+\frac{1}{1+c}\leq\frac{a+b+c+3}{4}$$

I tried AM-GM for the fraction on the LHS but got stuck from there.

Answer (score 6):

let $p=a+b+c,q=ab+bc+ca,r=abc$

Now it is easy to prove the following as $r=1$

- $pq\ge 9r=9$
- $p^2\ge 3q$

Now we have to prove $$4(3+2p+q)\le (p+3)(2+p+q)$$ or $$p^2+pq\ge 6+3p+q$$ $$p^2+9\ge 6+3p+q$$ using $q\le p^2/3$ $$\frac{2p^2}{3}-3p+3\ge 0$$ which is true as $p\ge 3$

Comment: Great! ..........

Comment: @Aqua thanks for the encouragement

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore Nice pqr method. (+1)

Answer (score 3):

Let $f(x) = \frac{1}{1 + x} - \frac{x+1}{4} + \frac{1}{2}\ln x$.
We have $f'(x) = \frac{(1-x)(x^2+x+2)}{4x(1+x)^2}$.
Thus, $f'(x) > 0$ on $(0, 1)$, and $f'(x) < 0$ on $(1, \infty)$.
Thus, $f(x)$ is strictly increasing on $(0, 1)$, and strictly decreasing on $(1, \infty)$.
Also $f(1) = 0$. Thus, $f(x) \le 0$ on $(0, \infty)$.

Thus, $f(a) + f(b) + f(c) \le 0$ which results in $\frac{1}{1+a} + \frac{1}{1+b} + \frac{1}{1+c}
\le \frac{a+b+c+3}{4}$ (using $\ln (abc) = 0$).

We are done.

Comment: This is nice and straight forward much better than mine(+1)

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore Thanks. I think both are nice.

Comment: What made you think of $ + 1/2 \ln x$?

Comment: @CalvinLin We want to find the form of
$f(x) = \frac{1}{1 + x} - \frac{x+1}{4} + m\ln x$ such that $f(x) \ge 0$ for all $x > 0$.
Clearly $f(1) = 0$.
By letting $f'(1) = 0$, we obtain $m = 1/2$.

Comment: lol, my point is that "of the form $ + m \ln x$" wasn't obvious to me. Was it experience that caused you to think of it?

Comment: @CalvinLin :-), it is a trick in the inequality of the form of $f(a) + f(b) + f(c) \ge 0$ subject to $abc = 1, a, b, c > 0$. The inequality is written as $\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} (f(a) + m \ln a) \ge 0$ for any $m$. So if we can choose appropriate $m$ such that $f(x) + m\ln x\ge 0$ for all $x>0$, then we are done. But sometimes it does not hold for all $x > 0$ but for $x > x_0$ with some $x_0 > 0$. For example, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3953789/a2-b2-c2-6-ge-3a-b-c-abc-1/3954835#3954835

Answer (score 1):

By [Schur's inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3815419) and AM-GM $$\begin{align*}x^3+y^3+z^3+3xyz\ge xy(x+y)+yz(y+z)+zx(x+z)&\\ \ge 2( {(xy)}^{3/2}+{(yz)}^{3/2}+{(zx)}^{3/2})\end{align*}\tag S$$

Now as $$\frac{1}{1+x}\le \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}$$ we have to prove $$a+b+c+3\sqrt[3]{abc}\ge 4\left(\frac{1}{2\sqrt{a}}+\frac{1}{2\sqrt{b}}+\frac{1}{2\sqrt{c}}\right)$$ or it suffices to prove $$a+b+c+3\sqrt[3]{abc}\ge 2\sqrt{ab}+2\sqrt{bc}+2\sqrt{ca}$$ which is just a direct consequence of inequality (S) and so we are done!

Note here $\sqrt[3]{abc}=\sqrt{abc}=1$ is used to normalize inequality