# If $x, y, z \in (0, 1)$ and $x+y+z = 2$, prove that $8(1-x)(1-y)(1-z) \leq xyz$.

Tags: calculus, inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

If $x, y, z \in (0, 1)$ and $x+y+z = 2$, prove that $8(1-x)(1-y)(1-z) \leq xyz$.

I found this in a Facebook group.

I start by doing the math in the LHS:
$8(1-x-y+xy-z+xz+yz-xyz) = 8(1-2+xy+xz+yz-xyz) = 8(xy+xz+yz-1-xyz)$.

Then we set $z=2-x-y$ and replace:

I get LHS = $x^2y+xy^2+2(x+y)-x^2-y^2-3xy-1$ but don't know how to proceed.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Wolfy say min{x y (2 - x - y) - 8 (1 - x) (1 - y) (x + y - 1)} = 0 at (x, y) = (2/3, 2/3) but doesn't say how.

Comment: The inequality is true for all positives ....

Answer (score 5):

As $0 \leq x, y, z \leq 1, (1-x), (1-y), (1-z) \geq 0$

Using A.M - G.M,

$(1-x) + (1-y) = z \geq 2 \sqrt{(1-x)(1-y)} \ $ (as $ \ x + y + z = 2$)

Similarly for $x, y$.

Multiplying them, we have

$xyz \geq 8 (1-x)(1-y)(1-z)$

Comment: is it possible to do it the Buffalo way

Comment: was just checking, gets more complicated... may be I am missing something.

Comment: @MathLover buffalo way can work see my answer which is just schur and its proof by BW is famous

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore yes saw it. Buffalo way does usually work... it was getting complicated the way I proceeded. I knew I was missing something.

Answer (score 3):

as $1-x=\frac{1}{2}(y+z-x)$ and similarly for others we have to prove  $$(x+y-z)(y+z-x)(x+z-y)\le xyz$$ which is [schur's inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3815419/prove-a3b3c33abc-ge-sum-cycabab)

Answer (score 1):

We let $a=1-x,b=1-y,c=1-z$ so that we have $a+b+c=1$ and $0 <  a,b,c < 1$.

Our new inequality now becomes $$8abc \leq (1-a)(1-b)(1-c)\\ \iff 8 \leq \left(\dfrac{1}{a}-1\right)\left(\dfrac{1}{b}-1\right)\left(\dfrac{1}{c}-1\right) \\ \iff 8 \leq \left(\dfrac{b+c}{a}\right)\left(\dfrac{c+a}{b}\right)\left(\dfrac{a+b}{c}\right)  $$ which means $(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)\geq 8abc$ which is true by [A.M-G.M inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means).

Equality occurs at $x=y=z=\dfrac{2}{3}$.

---

As for your approach, it is also correct. If you are substituting the value of $z$, making it a two variable inequality, you can form a quadratic equation taking everything to one side and set it's discriminant less than or equal to $0$.